# Push notification on window phone

Tags: java, windows-phone-7

I'm building a system of multi-platform push notification on the mobile operating system. My Server is written in JSP servlet. My problem encountered when building on window phone platform. I tried the test on the push on this operating system with the ASP server, they operate well. But because my server is JSP so I want to move from ASP to JSP for consistency. I have used the library mpns here ***https://github.com/notnoop/java-mpns*** to do this. But in the process of running, my server fails, and the message can not be sent to the client.Can you help me!

when I run it in debug to ***MpnsService service = MPNS.newService().build();***, server stop and not run again. And WebBrowser error message ***HTTP Status 500 - Servlet execution threw an exception***

Code server

```
public class SendAllMessagesServlet extends BaseServlet {

@Override
 protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
  throws IOException, ServletException {
  String uri=req.getParameter("uri");
  String title=req.getParameter("title");
  String content=req.getParameter("content");
  String page=req.getParameter("page");
  MpnsService service =
          MPNS.newService()
                  .build();
  TileNotification tile = MPNS.newNotification().tile()
          .count(1).title(title).backBackgroundImage("http://sample.com/image.png")
          .backTitle(content)
          .build();
  String subscriptionUri = uri;
  service.push(subscriptionUri, tile);

//PushNotificationWP push=new PushNotificationWP();
//push.PushNotif(title,content,page,uri);
getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/home").forward(req, resp);
 }

 }
```

Error on web browser

```
HTTP Status 500 - Servlet execution threw an exception

type Exception report message Servlet execution threw an exception description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet execution threw an exception root cause

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/logging/LogFactory
org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.<init>(AbstractHttpClient.java:187)
org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient.<init>(DefaultHttpClient.java:146)
mpns.MpnsServiceBuilder.build(MpnsServiceBuilder.java:185)
SendAllMessagesServlet.doPost(SendAllMessagesServlet.java:32)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
 note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/7.0.37 logs.
```

Comment: Have you resolved your issue ?

Answer (score 0):

You should include commons-loggin jar into your application. You can find it here [commons.apache.org](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-logging/download_logging.cgi)

After you download the file, open it and copy the file named commons-logging-1.1.3.jar ( assuming you've downloaded the last binary ) to your web application.

Good luck